# Bindable setter not called if value of property not changed?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

(*This may be too localized an issue but I will try to generalize it)*

**Question:** If a property `setter`is marked as `Bindable`, will it not get called if the new value is the same as the old value?

I am seeing the above behavior in a legacy project I have inherited: the setter is not getting called. If I don't declare the setter as `Bindable` then the setter is called no matter what the new value is.

Can anyone confirm that the above is the way things are designed to work with Binding?

This project uses `Binding` all over the place and there are no comments in the code so it is hard to tell what the dependencies are and which parts of the code depend on particular bindings. I'm trying to avoid making major changes but I also don't want to waste time trying to work around something which should be refactored.

**The property is bound:**

```
    [Bindable]
    protected var _source:AolMediaFile;
```

**The setter is bound:**

```
    [Bindable]
    public function set source(file:AolMediaFile):void{
          _source = file;
         // do some stuff with file
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So digging around here a bit more I came across this question: [Flex: Help me understand data Binding on getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677593/flex-help-me-understand-data-binding-on-getters-and-setters) which describes the code generated by declaring a setter or getter `Bindable`

So apparently in the generated code there is a check to see if the value is different:

```
public function set name(value:String)
{
    if (_name == value)
        return;
    _name = value;
    dispatchEvent(new Event("nameChanged"));
}
```

---

Comment: I think you misread the post. @Sunil D. posted this as his own code. He mentions that one can prevent the auto generated code from being generated by specifying the Event name in the tag. This way you could provide your own setter function that does not include a check if the value changes. But keep in mind that without the check a circular call of setters will cause problems. I have no experience with flex, this is just how I read his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The setter should only get called if the event source is `[Bindable]`. Data binding is basically a chain of events dispatched from source to target in a variety of scenarios. When you declare your property or setter as `[Bindable]`, that will basically change nothing in the behaviour in terms of side effects, as events are dispatched and listeners are generated. For example:

```
<your:Component source="{any.source.aolMediaFile}" />
```

Only when `any`, `source` and `aolMediaFile` are declared `[Bindable]`, `source` would be invoked. Having `source` declared as a `[Bindable]` property is only interesting, if a second component would be depending on your component's state

```
<your:Component id="yourComponent" source="{any.source.aolMediaFile}" />
<s:TextField text="{yourComponent.source}" />
```

If you would want to bind to a property of `AolMediaFile`, then the class or the specific property has to be be `[Bindable]` as well.

Usually the compiler prints warnings, if bindings can't be generated:

> warning: unable to bind to property 'source' on class 'Object'
>   (class is not an IEventDispatcher)

So check the source object, which are the source's host object's dependency and the compiler warnings.

Comment: That's why implementing the setters by hand is always more valuable as just generating the code since you can debug every single step. Glad you found the source of the problem.